# Best way to reduce risk of server-side report taking up too much memory

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-performance

we have a service, Tomcat-Spring-JPA running on top of MySQL.

A part of our service is a reports function. We have different clients of different sizes and therefor, different amounts of data.

When they run reports, they select dates and various other parameters, send them to the server, and the server creates PDF's, XLS sheets etc.

We were concerned that if they could select any date periods it might take up too much memory, so we made some estimations and came up with a "max time period" for reports.

This is not optimal for a number of reasons, so now that we have more time, we're looking at alternatives.

The best i've come up with so far is basically to have a "max number of rows" instead, i.e. do a count(*) of the query with all the params and if too much data, tell the user they have to reduce the date period.

I have a couple of concerns though, and am hoping for some feedback:

1. Won't the count(*) itself take up quite some memory?
2. Is there a better way to do this that i haven't thought about? (I don't want to do paging or similar, if they're running a report they'd expect to get all the data)

Comment: Did you try to analyse _why_ report_ generation requires so much memory? Probably the right way is to try to optimize algorithm that generates reports, so the limitations will become irrelevant.

Comment: No matter how much you optimize, you'd eventually run the risk of running out of memory if enough users run simultaneously. I'm not running this as a cloud service(yet), so i try to reduce overhead and risk where i can. Hope you see where i'm coming from.

Comment: memory concsumption depends on your implementation. You are right that if all 8 billion people will start to generate 10 years hourly report using your application you will experience memory issues. However I guess that you have less users, so _probably_ some analysis of your report generation mechanism can help to avoid memory problems.

Comment: Yeah, but i'm not saying that i think our reports take up an *unusual* amount of memory, i'm just saying that if we let users select any time interval, we might run out of memory if the user selects a time period of 6 years for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count(*) won't take significant amount of memory.
2. I would define time ranges to reduce the amount of data. E.g. if selected interval is less than 15 days it's the report time interval is DAYS.

If the interval is more than 15 days but less than 100 days the report time interval is WEEK

If the interval is more than 100 days but less than 200 days the report time interval is MONTH

If the interval is more than 200 days but less than 500 days the report time interval is QARTER

If the interval is more than 500 days the report time interval is YEAR.

Thus amount of rows in the report is always reasonable but if user want to investigate some interval deeper then shorter period is selected and more detailed report is generated